# update BindingList from another thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization

How do I modify a `BindingList` bound to a DataGridView from another thread ?

```
class A {
  public BindingList<int> BindingSource = new BindingList<int>();

  // to be called from another thread
  public void Update(int a) {
    BindingSource.Add(a);
  }
}

A a = new A();
DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
dgv.DataSource = a.BindingSource;
```

Comment: What did you try? Where's your other thread? It's not clear what you're asking. Did you have a problem modifying your `BindingList` from another thread? Please provide a good [mcve] that shows clearly what you're trying to do, and explain precisely what that code does and what you want it to do instead.